# Correct syntax for concatenating multiple columns in Query select

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

in one of my sheets I have two columns of First Name and Last Name, within that sheet I have a third column that joins those two together with the concatenate formula. A query elsewhere then selected that column to output.

What I'd like to do is have those columns joined within the query however I cant find the correct syntax. Currently I have :

`=query(nrDataSource, 
"select C," & Sheet1!$B$4 & " where " & Sheet!$B$4 & " contains ':'",0)`

Column C is the joined column and what I want is :

`=query(nrDataSource, 
"select A,B," & Sheet1!$B$4 & " where " & Sheet!$B$4 & " contains ':'",0)`

And have A & B joined together with a space in between in one output cell.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Google sheets [query syntax](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) doesn't have concatenating option.

But you may use `filter` function instead.

```
=FILTER(A:A&B:B,REGEXMATCH(C:C,"\:"))
```

[image]

`REGEXMATCH` part of formula doing the same as `contains` in query.

### **Additional options**

You may also:

1. add another conditions into filter: `=FILTER(A:A&B:B,REGEXMATCH(C:C,"\:"), ...)`
2. make concatination and then query the resulting array: `=query({ARRAYFORMULA(A:A&A:B),C:D},"select Col1, Col2")`